# BufferStrategy lagging

Tags: java, graphics

My desktop application lags. I think something is wrong in the java.awt.image.BufferStrategy.

```
    private void render() {
    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();

    if (bs == null) {
        this.createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    // drawing
    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
}
```

I didn't even start drawing. I have used the same thing in another project  and it worked for example if the render method looks like that, it works fine.

```
private void render(){
BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();

    if (bs == null ){
        this.createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    // drawing
    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
     int row;   // Row number, from 0 to 7
     int col;   // Column number, from 0 to 7
     int x,y;   // Top-left corner of square

     for ( row = 0;  row < 8;  row++ ) {
        for ( col = 0;  col < 8;  col++) {
           x = col * 70;
           y = row * 70;
           if ( (row % 2) == (col % 2) )
              g.setColor(Color.white);
           else
              g.setColor(Color.black);
           g.fillRect(x, y, 70, 70);
        } 
     }
    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync(); 
}
```

The core things are the same. Why the first one lags in the same conditions?

Comment: Without `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync(); ` I can't even terminate my program. The mouse starts moving slowly.

Answer (score -1):

Try removing:

```
    for ( row = 0;  row < 8;  row++ ) {
    for ( col = 0;  col < 8;  col++) {
       x = col * 70;
       y = row * 70;
       if ( (row % 2) == (col % 2) )
          g.setColor(Color.white);
       else
          g.setColor(Color.black);
       g.fillRect(x, y, 70, 70);
    } 
 }
```